# How can I give a user the permission to create a field but not to change it?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I wanna a user to create a record but later dun give it the right to change the value of that field. should I do it By overriding create and write  methods? is it possible to write such code:

```html
field1: fields.float(string='Field',write=['base.GROUP_ID']),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work create a status field this field is a compute field when it's true the field1 will be read only. Because i'm on my phone i'm not going to writr the hole code just try to understand the idea

```
     status = field.Boolean(compute='compute_status') 


        def compute_status(self):
                 for rec in self:
                        # first check of the use belong to the group that have full acces
                         if self.env.user.has_group('group_id') :
                                  rec.status = False
                          # then check if the record is saved in databse 
                          # unsaved records There id is instance of NewId it's a dummy class used for this
                         elif instanceOf(NewId ,rec.id) :
                                     rec.status = False # here all users can fill the field when the record is not created yet but cannot edit
                         else :
                                   rec.status = True # if record is saved and user is not in group_id make field readonly or invisible as you want
```

Now create your field and use status property to make it readonly when status field is True .
As you can see  my answer is algorithme more than a code sorry for sysntax errors

Comment: is that possible for a specified user ?

Comment: Yes it can be don add a compute field that have the current user and a make your field readonly based on the value of that field don't make the compute field stored so odoo recomputr the value every. Time

Comment: @CherifOdoo please edit the last comment into your answer. A code snippet as example would be very nice to have ;-)

Comment: Can you explain what is the condition exactly

Comment: I'm so sorry ... I dun understand it, maybe I wasn't clear to explain what I need

Comment: field1: fields.float(string='Field'), what I need is that a user who belong for example to  'base.GROUP_ID2' can create and write (field1) and other users who dun belong to it can just create... so there is no conditions just ones can create and write some fields and others can only create

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to do this is to create a group to which the user will belong, then set in the `ir.model.access` a rule, with the rights you want, for that particular group.

Ask if you need more help.

---

EDIT

You can define a view, that inherit from the original one, but is accessible only for the user group, like:

```
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref(' < your group > ')])]"/>
```

and there you redefine the field making it readonly. That's it.

Comment: That only works on model tier access. But the requirement is to have write rights on a field.

Comment: That wouldn't fulfill his requirement, too. He needs the user to set a value initially on a field, and after to set this field readonly for the same user.

Comment: You can add a check on the id of the new record inside the field you are redefining. Or you can even add it on the field itself, so the user can set it until it is False or None.